# Change regular expression from PRCE to ICU to comply with stringr usage

Tags: r, regex, stringr

Recently I asked a question to create a complex regular expression to split a string ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60739842/split-r-string-at-spaces-but-not-when-the-space-is-between-single-quotes)).  I was working with base R so everything worked fine.  However, I now want to use the same expression into an other piece of my code which follow the tidyverse "environment" (I want to use `tidyr::separate_rows`) and it doesn't work because my pattern is `PRCE` and `stringr` uses only the ICU library.

Reproducible example:

```
vec <- c("'01'", "'01' '02'", 
         "#bateau", "#bateau #batiment",
         "#'autres 32'", "#'autres 32' #'batiment 30'", "#'autres 32' #'batiment 30' #'contenu 31'",
         "#'34'", "#'34' #'33' #'35'")
```

I have the previous string that I need to split everywhere there is a space (), except if the space is between `'`.  @Wiktor Stribiżew kindly answer my question and gave me this pattern `'[^']*'(*SKIP)(*F)|\\s+` which worked perfectly in a `strsplit` call:

```
strsplit(vec, "'[^']*'(*SKIP)(*F)|\\s+", perl=TRUE)
[[1]]
[1] "'01'"

[[2]]
[1] "'01'" "'02'"

[[3]]
[1] "#bateau"

[[4]]
[1] "#bateau"   "#batiment"

[[5]]
[1] "#'autres 32'"

[[6]]
[1] "#'autres 32'"   "#'batiment 30'"

[[7]]
[1] "#'autres 32'"   "#'batiment 30'" "#'contenu 31'" 

[[8]]
[1] "#'34'"

[[9]]
[1] "#'34'" "#'33'" "#'35'"
```

However, when I tried the same pattern a tidyverse function, I got this error:

```
stringr::str_split(vec, "'[^']*'(*SKIP)(*F)|\\s+")
Error in stri_split_regex(string, pattern, n = n, simplify = simplify,  : 
  Syntax error in regexp pattern. (U_REGEX_RULE_SYNTAX)
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45869436/running-regex-in-r-using-str-extract-all-has-regexp-not-yet-implemented), @Wiktor Stribiżew was kind enough again to explain the problem which is because this is a `PCRE` expression while the tidyverse uses `ICU`

Is there a way to make my expression work in the tidyverse?  If not, what expression would work?  Please note that my example use `strsplit` as it is simpler to explain the problem.  However, at the end, I want to use the `tidyr::separate_rows` function explaining why I need a tidyverse compatible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your example, you could simply target and split spaces followed by a `#` with this regex `\\s(?=#)`.

In case you need something more flexible, one solution is to first target and replace the spaces you want to split using your previous regex `'[^']*'(*SKIP)(*F)|\\s+` and `gsub`, which accepts perl regular expression. Replace the matched spaces with an anchor (unique character or chain of characters) and separates your rows based on this anchor.

```
vec <- c("'01'", "'01' '02'", 
         "#bateau", "#bateau #batiment",
         "#'autres 32'", "#'autres 32' #'batiment 30'", "#'autres 32' #'batiment 30' #'contenu 31'",
         "#'34'", "#'34' #'33' #'35'")

vec %>% 
  tibble(my_col = .) %>% 
  mutate(my_col = gsub("'[^']*'(*SKIP)(*F)|\\s+", "_-_", my_col, perl = TRUE)) %>% 
  separate_rows(my_col, sep = "_-_")

# A tibble: 16 x 1
   my_col        
   <chr>         
 1 '01'          
 2 '01'          
 3 '02'          
 4 #bateau       
 5 #bateau       
 6 #batiment     
 7 #'autres 32'  
 8 #'autres 32'  
 9 #'batiment 30'
10 #'autres 32'  
11 #'batiment 30'
12 #'contenu 31' 
13 #'34'         
14 #'34'         
15 #'33'         
16 #'35'
```

Comment: That is clever, I really like the `gsub`approch.  Thanks!